# Arrow length for hunting

Tags: bow-hunting, archery

So, from a non-hunting archer's point of view, the arrow length is `drawLength + 2" - fineTuning`

Is there any difference for a hunter or is calculated just the same way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hunting arrows fly differently due to the broadheads so the "fineTuning" variable would be slightly different.
I shoot the same bow and arrows (points and broadheads weight the same) for field and hunting but I have a set of arrows for field and a set for hunting.

That said, as I shoot a recurve barebow style, I wouldn't notice much difference between my two sets. I only have two sets to so it makes easier to pack when I'm going to the field or hunting. :)